# Seleccionar registros mes pasado sin importar el año

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta query

```
SELECT COUNT(VENTA_ID) AS 'VENTAS'
FROM VENTAS
WHERE MONTH( VENTA_FECHA ) = MONTH( NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

La cual me trae un conteo de las ventas que se hicieron el mes pasado, y estaba pensando, ¿Que pasará cuando cambiemos de año? Esta consulta me regresará todos los registros donde su mes coincida, por ejemplo a principios del siguiente año el mes será el 12 en esta consulta, pero, ¿Si tengo registros del 2017/12? También me los traerá por que el mes coincide, estaba pensando en agregar

```
AND YEAR( VENTA_FECHA ) = YEAR( NOW() )
```

Sin embargo, esto me regresará por ejemplo 12/2019 ya que el siguiente año será el 2019.

¿Cómo le puedo hacer para conseguir el objetivo? Osea, como puedo traer solo los registros del mes anterior y el año anterior o en curso según sea el caso.

Estaba pensando en utilizar `BETWEEN` pero no se bien como construirlo

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla es generar una fecha de un mes anterior al del día y verificar las dos partes de la misma que nos interesan: `MONTH()` y `YEAR()`. Algo así:

```
SELECT @MesAnterior =  NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH

SELECT *
       FROM VENTAS
       WHERE MONTH(VENTA_FECHA) = MONTH(@MesAnterior)
             AND YEAR(VENTA_FECHA) = YEAR(@MesAnterior)
```

**Importante**

Siempre que trabajemos con funciones no determinísticas como `Now()` es fundamental tomar una sola lectura de la misma, técnicamente, si usáramos `Now()` directamente para luego calcular el `MONTH()` y el `YEAR()` existe la posibilidad muy remota (por supuesto) de ejecutar la consulta el `31/12/18 23:59:59` y que nos retorne un año y el mes del siguiente.